# How to detect if a date is within this or next week in java?

Tags: java, date

If I have a date of an event, such as 2011-01-03, how to detect if it is within this or next week in java ? Any sample code ?

Edit :

I thought it was a simple question, it turned out more complex than I thought, what I meat this week is : from this past Sun to this Sat, next week is from next Sun to the Sat after that.

Comment: How do you define week? What about in other cultures where the definition is different from the one you use in your culture? What should happen then?

Comment: Just standard Sun Mon .. Sat week.

Comment: @Frank There is no standard that I know of that defines a week as Sunday through Saturday. That is common in the United States but not most of the world, especially not in business. Standards such as [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) define a week as Monday to Sunday and define a week number of the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this :

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SUNDAY);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));      // This past Sunday [ May include today ]
c.add(Calendar.DATE,7);
System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));      // Next Sunday
c.add(Calendar.DATE,7);
System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));      // Sunday after next
```

The result :

```
Sun 2010/12/26 00:00:00
Sun 2011/01/02 00:00:00
Sun 2011/01/09 00:00:00
```

Any day between the first two is this week, anything between the last two is next week.

Comment: Not the best answer. The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are so bad that even Sun/Oracle gave up on them. The new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) is now bundled in Java 8 to supplant the old classes. [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) inspired java.time and has some superior features.

Answer (score 8):

It partly depends on what you mean by "this week" and "next week"... but with [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) it's certainly easy to find out whether it's in "today or the next 7 days" as it were:

```
LocalDate event = getDateFromSomewhere();
LocalDate today = new LocalDate();
LocalDate weekToday = today.plusWeeks(1);
LocalDate fortnightToday = weekToday.plusWeeks(1);

if (today.compareTo(event) <= 0 && event.compareTo(weekToday) < 0)
{
    // It's within the next 7 days
}
else if (weekToday.compareTo(event) <= 0 && event.compareTo(fornightToday) < 0)
{
    // It's next week
}
```

EDIT: To get the Sunday to Saturday week, you'd probably want:

```
LocalDate startOfWeek = new LocalDate().withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY);
```

then do the same code as the above, but relative to `startOfWeek`.

Comment: Isn't the first comparison of the else if redundant?

Comment: Also, he clarified that he means a Sun-Sat week, not just the next 7 days.

Comment: @Matthew: Why? The event could be in the past, for example.

Comment: you're right, I misread it. :)  However, you can pull the `today.compareTo(event)` out into its own `if` containing the `if` and `else if`.  Then, the comparison I mentioned would be unnecessary.

Comment: @Matthew: You could, yes. Personally I like the way that each pair of comparisons does everything required to test the conditions... but yes, it's slightly less efficient than it could be. I've added an edit for the day-of-week bit.

Comment: @JonSkeet what we pass here getDateFromSomewhere();

Comment: @lulu: Well wherever we're getting the date of the event from. We can't tell that from the question.

Answer (score 3):

Most answers here do not satisfy me. They either use the outdated `Calendar`-API (excusable in old answers given in times before Java 8, and it is hence not fair to criticize such answers), or they are even partially wrong or unnecessarily complex. For example, the most upvoted answer by Jon Skeet suggests to determine the first day of week by the Joda-expression `new LocalDate().withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY)`. But such code uses the ISO-definition of a week starting on Monday with the consequence that if the current date is not on Sunday the code would produce next Sunday and not previous Sunday as desired by the OP. Joda-Time is incapable of handling non-ISO weeks.

**Another minor flaw of other answers is not to care about if the current AND NEXT week contains a given date - as requested by the OP.** So here my improved suggestion in modern Java:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(); // involves the system time zone and clock of system
LocalDate startOfCurrentWeek =
  today.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
LocalDate endOfNextWeek =
  startOfCurrentWeek.plusDays(13);

LocalDate event = LocalDate.of(2011, 1, 3); // input of example given by OP

boolean matchingResult =
  !(event.isBefore(startOfCurrentWeek) || event.isAfter(endOfNextWeek));
```

Side note: The question has inspired me to add a [small enhancement](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/DateInterval.html#ofCurrentWeek-net.time4j.base.TimeSource-net.time4j.tz.TZID-net.time4j.Weekday-) to the class `DateInterval` in my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) how to determine the current calendar week in a very generic way.

Answer (score 2):

Although old question - is still relevant. The most upvoted answer here is correct wrt to Joda-time and wrt to JDK8 as well with some syntax changes. Here's one that might help those who are looking around in JDK8 world.

```
 public static boolean isLocalDateInTheSameWeek(LocalDate date1, LocalDate date2) {
    LocalDate sundayBeforeDate1 = date1.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
    LocalDate saturdayAfterDate1 = date1.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY));
    return  ((date2.isEqual(sundayBeforeDate1) || date2.isAfter(sundayBeforeDate1)) 
            && (date2.isEqual(saturdayAfterDate1) || date2.isBefore(saturdayAfterDate1)));
}
```

Comment: It’s readable from the code, but still worth mentioning: This checks whether `date2` falls within the week (Sun–Sat) of `date1`. So to find out if `date2` is within current week, pass today as `date1`.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use Calendar. Create new instance of it for your sample event date. Then, compare WEEK_OF_YEAR for current date, and the date of your event.

Comment: I would strongly recommend *not* using Calendar, as it's a generally *horrible* API. Using DAY_OF_YEAR will make it really tricky for a week which covers two different years...

Comment: Jon, I actually meant WEEK_OF_YEAR, which I tried to correct immediately. I do hope I have understood the question correctly..

Comment: @Arturs: Right, WEEK_OF_YEAR would help... but to check for "next week" would still be relatively tricky, as you'd need to check for wrap-around and which year it was too. I'd still suggest using Joda Time.

Comment: .. as for Calendar - I also didn't like it at first until I had to learn it well (for examination), and then I found it quite convenient to use in some cases (when I had to do tricky manipulations with date), so might it be matter of habit? But I'll definitely have look at Joda Time, so that I have two 'Date Manipulation APIs' to compare.

Comment: @Arturs: Joda Time is better in many, many ways. A lot of that is because it distinguishes between the many different types involved - dates, times, dates and times, those which are local vs those with time zones etc. Also the immutability aspect leads to it being significantly simpler to reason about.

Comment: @Jon Thank you. I also scanned through "Why Joda Time?" and "User Guide" sections, and now I see the motivation behind the lib, as well as how does it outperform JDK Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

for those that has to stick to JDK 7 and can't use joda.time, I wrote this method and tested.

```
public static boolean inSameWeek(Date date1, Date date2) {
    if (null == date1 || null == date2) {
        return false;
    }

    Calendar earlier = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar later = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (date1.before(date2)) {
        earlier.setTime(date1);
        later.setTime(date2);
    } else {
        earlier.setTime(date2);
        later.setTime(date1);
    }
    if (inSameYear(date1, date2)) {
        int week1 = earlier.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        int week2 = later.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        if (week1 == week2) {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        int dayOfWeek = earlier.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
        earlier.add(Calendar.DATE, 7 - dayOfWeek);
        if (inSameYear(earlier.getTime(), later.getTime())) {
            int week1 = earlier.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
            int week2 = later.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
            if (week1 == week2) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean inSameYear(Date date1, Date date2) {
    if (null == date1 || null == date2) {
        return false;
    }
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(date1);
    int year1 = cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(date2);
    int year2 = cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if (year1 == year2)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Calendar API to retrieve the week for a given day.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(somedate);
int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: But don't for get the corner cases of a year's last week!

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Testing a pair of `LocalDate` objects by using `org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange` class with a `TemporalAdjuster` named `ta` that determines the first day of the week.

```
        LocalDateRange.of( 
            localDate1.with( ta ) , 
            localDate1.with( ta ).plusWeeks( 1 ) 
        )
        .contains( 
            localDate2 
        )
```

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

The [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project adds additional functionality to the *java.time* classes built into Java (defined by JSR 310).

Among the added classes is [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html). This class represents a span-of-time attached to the timeline. In other words, a pair of `LocalDate` objects. This class offers handy methods for comparing, such as `overlaps`, `contains`, and `abuts`. Here we need [`equals`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Define a method where you pass your two dates plus the first day of the week (a [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum object).

We use a `TemporalAdjuster` found in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class to determine the date of the first day of the week. Then add a week to get the end of the week (per Half-Open definition of a span-of-time).

We could be cute and check to see if both dates are the same. A worthy check if such a case is likely often in your app.

For week 2, let's use a one-liner as alternative syntax.

```
public boolean inSameWeek ( LocalDate localDate1 , LocalDate localDate2 , DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek ) {
    Objects.requireNonNull( localDate1 ) ;  // … ditto for other arguments.

    if( localDate1.isEqual( localDate2 ) ) { return true ; }

    TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( firstDayOfWeek ) ;

    LocalDate weekStart1 = localDate1.with( ta ) ;
    LocalDate weekStop1 = weekStart1.plusWeeks( 1 ) ;
    LocalDateRange week1 = LocalDateRange.of( weekStart1 , weekStop1 ) ;

    LocalDateRange week2 = 
        LocalDateRange.of(
            localDate2.with( ta ) ,
            localDate2.with( ta ).plusWeeks( 1 ) 
        )
    ;

    // Compare the weeks.
    return week1.equals( week2 ) ;
}
```

Or even more compact.

```
public boolean inSameWeek ( LocalDate localDate1 , LocalDate localDate2 , DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek ) {
    Objects.requireNonNull( localDate1 ) ;  // … ditto for other arguments.

    if( localDate1.isEqual( localDate2 ) ) { return true ; }

    TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( firstDayOfWeek ) ;
    return 
        LocalDateRange.of( 
            localDate1.with( ta ) , 
            localDate1.with( ta ).plusWeeks( 1 ) 
        )
        .equals( 
            LocalDateRange.of( 
                localDate2.with( ta ) , 
                localDate2.with( ta ).plusWeeks( 1 ) 
            )
        )
    ;
}
```

We really do not need that second week. We only care if the first determined week [contains](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#contains(java.time.LocalDate)) the second passed date argument.

```
public boolean inSameWeek ( LocalDate localDate1 , LocalDate localDate2 , DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek ) {
    Objects.requireNonNull( localDate1 ) ;  // … ditto for other arguments.

    if( localDate1.isEqual( localDate2 ) ) { return true ; }

    TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( firstDayOfWeek ) ;
    return 
        LocalDateRange.of( 
            localDate1.with( ta ) , 
            localDate1.with( ta ).plusWeeks( 1 ) 
        )
        .contains( 
            localDate2
        )
    ;
}
```

Use it.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis") ) ;

boolean sameWeek = this.inSameWeek( localDate , today , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
```

Caveat: I ran none of this code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in Java 8

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate twoWeeksBefore = today.minusWeeks(2);
LocalDate checkDate = someObject.getSomeDate();

if(checkDate.compareTo(twoWeeksBefore) > 0) {
    // do something if checkDate is within last two weeks
} else {
    // do something if checkDate is on or before last two weeks
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for me, this didn't detect a case like Sunday vs 1 day before (Saturday) which are different weeks. I'm going to have to go with a `weekOfYear()` approach.